# Trouble removing parts of text from string

Tags: jquery, arrays, regex, each

I created a basic jQuery function that pulls the text out a each  with a class name of .productPrice. It stores all of the products price text into an array name priceTexts. The problem now is that I need to remove the dollar signs that also get stored in array. Here is the function that only pulls the prices and save them into the array:

```
var priceTexts = [];
$(".productPrice").each(function() {
    priceTexts.push($(this).text());
});
```

Now, I've tried to add the following into the .each function, thinking this would automaticly remove the dollar sign before the price even gets stored into the array:

```
var priceTexts = [];
$(".productPrice").each(function() {

    $(this).text().replace("$", "");

    priceTexts.push($(this).text());
});
```

I haven't had any luck the the above code... I've also tried to use an array.each function after this one, using regexp to remove the dollar sign from each string, but haven't had any success with this method either. I know this is a pretty basic function, but I can't seem to figure it out! Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us your HTML; is there only one `$` per element matched?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace them while adding in array:

```
var priceTexts = [];
$(".productPrice").each(function() { 
    priceTexts.push($(this).text().replace("$", ""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var priceTexts = [];
$(".productPrice").each(function() {
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/$/g, ""));
priceTexts.push($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var priceTexts = [];
$(".productPrice").each(function() {

$(this).text($(this).text().replace("$", "")); // correct this line 

priceTexts.push($(this).text());
 });
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding some more explanations